# How to get rid of Qualitative predictors in Data set

Tags: r

Trying to use the range() function and take out my Qualitative predictors (2 total), instead of listing all the Quantitative (7 total).

```
require(ISLR)
data(Auto)
range(Auto$mpg)
range(Auto$cylinders)
range(Auto$displacement)
range(Auto$horsepower)
range(Auto$weight)
range(Auto$acceleration)
range(Auto$year)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am only seeing one qualitative variable, `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out which columns are numeric with an `sapply` loop, creating a logical index `i`. Then `sapply` function `range` only to those columns.
Also, there is no need to load an entire package just to access one of its data sets, function `data` has a `package` argument that can be used to tell R where to find the data set to be loaded.

```r
data(Auto, package = "ISLR")
str(Auto)
#> 'data.frame':    392 obs. of  9 variables:
#>  $ mpg         : num  18 15 18 16 17 15 14 14 14 15 ...
#>  $ cylinders   : num  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
#>  $ displacement: num  307 350 318 304 302 429 454 440 455 390 ...
#>  $ horsepower  : num  130 165 150 150 140 198 220 215 225 190 ...
#>  $ weight      : num  3504 3693 3436 3433 3449 ...
#>  $ acceleration: num  12 11.5 11 12 10.5 10 9 8.5 10 8.5 ...
#>  $ year        : num  70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
#>  $ origin      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ name        : Factor w/ 304 levels "amc ambassador brougham",..: 49 36 231 14 161 141 54 223 241 2 ...

i <- sapply(Auto, is.numeric)
t(sapply(Auto[i], range))
#>              [,1]   [,2]
#> mpg             9   46.6
#> cylinders       3    8.0
#> displacement   68  455.0
#> horsepower     46  230.0
#> weight       1613 5140.0
#> acceleration    8   24.8
#> year           70   82.0
#> origin          1    3.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The following is a one-liner (ouput omited).

```r
t(sapply(Auto[sapply(Auto, is.numeric)], range))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>